# How can I see traffic bandwidth and data usage of GCP's Load balancer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I need to know how much traffic bandwidth is used in our service. How can I see it? Does GCP provide the way? e.g. on Dashboard or APIs.
I can see the number of requests per sec (RPS) on the dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the only way I have found how to do this is to go to do it from within the Google Cloud Console Web interface (not Stackdriver).

Go to (as of Jan 2018):

- Main menu > Networking > Network Services
- "Load Balancing" menu option
- "Load Balancers" tab
- {my load balancer name} list item
- "Monitoring" sub-tab

There you see a couple of charts with filter options. The chart's Y axis is the RPS (requests per second) that this load balancer is handling.

I would like to know how to see this same chart in a Dashboard in Stackdriver, but I have not found how to aggregate to RPS, I only get Requests Sum...